# Reducer code for grouping the words by their lenght

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, iterator, reducers

In MapReduce Program, Reducer method is taking a inputs form Mapper as "Words" and it's length.

```
 ex.input :-
         Hi -2
         how - 3
         are  -3 
         you - 3 
         ?   - 1
```

Now I need to write a Reducer in such a way that it gives a output by grouping "Word length" and all words comes under in one category on the basis of word' length as below

```
ex. Output :-
       1  - [?]
       2  - [hi]
       3  - [how, are, you]
```

Here is my Mapper program :

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> Output, Reporter arg3) throws IOException {
    String s = values.toString();

    for (String word : s.split(" ")) {
        if (word.length() > 0 ) {
            Output.collect(new Text(word), new IntWritable(word.length()));
        }

    }
}
```

How is a Reduce program ?

Comment: Without any intention to offend, if you cannot design a program as simple as that in MapReduce, perhaps you should go back and read some MapReduce fundamentals (e.g., a tutorial or a book). It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your reducer to group by the length, you'll have to have the mapper emit the length as keys and the words as values, thus instead of:

```
     Hi -2
     how - 3
     are  -3 
     you - 3 
     ?   - 1
```

emit

```
     2 - Hi
     3 - how
     3 - are
     3 - you
     1 - ?
```

Then, you have the ready result as input to the reducer already. Depending on the system you use, you can switch off the reducer alltogether or use a simply identity function.

Comment: Thanks , it work for me .  What if,  I  want to collect as  "Word.length() + sum of word present of same group + all the words " . ex. "3  - 5 [how, are, you, got , the]"  as Output of Reducer

Comment: Then, you have a different map-reduce problem. One is as described above, the other would be to emit (length,1) from the mapper and reduce to (length, sum).
From the top of my head I cannot think of a solution which solves both in one run.

Comment: Funny how these things stick... Basically, the solution is quite simple. You map as described above, reduce from (number, single_word) to (number, list_of_words) and emit ((number, list_length), list_of_words) in the end.